# Can't find link to download file on an <a> for a scraping bot

Tags: html, web-scraping

I love beat saber and couldn't find any script to download the songs automatically, so i want to make one.
Here is the issue :
On this webpage : https://beatsaver.com/browse/hot
when i inspect the "Download" button on one song, the  is like this :

`a href="/" Download /a`

I'd like to retrieve some kind of link so i can just give that to my script for it to download it in a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website get data from `https://beatsaver.com/api/maps/hot/[n]?automapper=1` (follow Network tab at Dev tool, `n` starts at `0`) which are JSON files. The download links are in this data frame (`directDownload` column):
*(I use R)*

```
data <- 
  purrr::map_dfr(
    0:20,
    function(i) 
      jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0("https://beatsaver.com/api/maps/hot/", i, "?automapper=1"))$docs
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! I'm still missing some knowledge to get the R script you gave me, but your intel was enough for me to find another way to retrieve the direct download key with the help of the network tab ! (found a stable url and i just have to add the last part of the "one clicktm" button to it to get the direct download of the song)
Thanks !